# Parallel transport as algebra isomorphism

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume that there is an smooth structure of the matrix algebra $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ on fibers of the tangent bundle of a $n^2$ dimensional manifold.

> Is there a Riemannian metric on $M$ such that all operator of parallel transports would be an algebra isomorphism?

Comment: Have you tried a left invariant metric on $GL(n)$?

Comment: There're plenty of examples with non-tangent underlying bundle that you likely already know: take Riemannian $2^{4k + a}$-dimensional mfd M, $a = 0, 1$, find some integrable subbundle $E$ of $TM$ of dimension $8k + 2a$ (equivalenly, some foliation of such dimension). $Cl(E)$ can be the bundle with this property. (I guess it's never isomorphic to $TM$ unless M is parallelizable, and therefore doesn't answer your question).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a classic theorem in linear algebra that any ($\mathbb{R}$-linear) automorphism $\phi$ of the the ring $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is *inner*, i.e., of the form $\phi(x) = axa^{-1}$ for some invertible $a\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.  In particular, the group of automorphisms of the algebra is $\mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, a simple group of dimension $n^2{-}1$, whose maximal compact subgroups are all conjugate to $\mathrm{PO}(n) = \mathrm{O}(n)/\{\pm I_n\}$.

To avoid trivial cases, assume that $n>1$ and, at least to start with, assume also that $M$ be simply connected.  If $M^{n^2}$ carried a Riemannian metric $g$ whose Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ preserved an $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ algebra structure on $TM$, then, because its holonomy would be compact, there would be an underlying $\nabla$-parallel $\mathrm{PO}(n)$-structure on $M$.

Now, the representation of $\mathrm{PO}(n)$ on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is reducible, being the sum of three terms:
$$
M_n(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}{\cdot}I_n\ \oplus\ A_n(\mathbb{R})\ \oplus\ S_n(\mathbb{R}), 
$$
where $A_n(\mathbb{R})\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$ consists of the skew-symmetric $n$-by-$n$ matrices, while $S_n(\mathbb{R})\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$ consists of the traceless symmetric $n$-by-$n$ matrices.

When $n>2$, the representations of $\mathrm{PO}(n)$ on both $A_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $S_n(\mathbb{R})$ are irreducible and (almost) faithful. By the Bianchi identities, the two corresponding subbundles of $TM$ will be $\nabla$-parallel and, hence by the reducibility of the holonomy, the metric on $M$ will locally split as a product into three factors  The (almost) faithfulness of two of the representations guarantees (by the second Bianchi identity), that the curvature of $\nabla$ must vanish identically.  Hence, the only case that occurs is the locally flat structure.  One can, of course, do things with open sets and discrete quotients, but, locally, the flat case is the only case.

When $n=2$, things are different.  The group $\mathrm{PO}(2)$ acts on $A_2(\mathbb{R})\simeq \mathbb{R}$ as $\{\pm1\}\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$, and it acts on $S_2(\mathbb{R})\simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathrm{O}(2)$.  Since $M$ is simply connected, it follows that, at least locally, $(M,g)$ can be written as a metric product
$$
M = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times \Sigma,
$$ 
where $(\Sigma,h)$ is an oriented Riemannian surface, which, hence, has an associated orthogonal complex structure $J$ and area form $\omega$.  Then one can define an $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ structure on $T_pM$ = $T_x\mathbb{R}\times T_y\mathbb{R}\times T_z\Sigma = \mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}\oplus T_z\Sigma$ by the rule
$$
(a,b,v)(a',b',v') = (aa'{-}bb'{+}h(v,v'),\ ab'{+}a'b{+}\omega(v,v'),\ av'{+}a'v{+}b\,Jv' {+} b'\,Jv).
$$
Thus, the general solution essentially depends on a Riemannian metric in dimension $2$, which is one function of two variables, up to diffeomorphism.

If one is willing to consider pseudo-Riemannian metrics instead of only Riemannian ones, there are other solutions.  For example, when $n=2$, $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts preserving the irreducible splitting
$$
M_2(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}{\cdot}I_2\ \oplus Z_2(\mathbb{R})
$$
where $Z_2(\mathbb{R})\simeq \mathbb{R}^3$ is the space of $2$-by-$2$ traceless matrices.  The action of $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ on $Z_2(\mathbb{R})$ preserves a Lorentzian inner product $\langle,\rangle$ that satisfies $\langle v,v\rangle = \det(v)$, so that $v^2 = -\langle v,v\rangle I_2$ and the 'outer' or 'skew' product $[v,w] = vw-wv$.

Consequently, if $(M^4,g)$ is a simply-connected Lorentzian $4$-manifold whose holonomy preserves a $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ algebra structure on $TM$, then $M$ can be written locally as a metric product 
$$
M^4 = \mathbb{R} \times \Sigma^3
$$
where $(\Sigma^3,h)$ is an oriented Lorentzian $3$-manifold and $g$-parallel algebra structure on $TM= T\mathbb{R}\oplus T\Sigma$ can be written in the form
$$
(a,v)(a',v') = (aa'-h(v,v'),\ av' + a'v + v{\times}v')
$$
where $v{\times}v' = \ast_h(v\wedge v')$ and where $\ast_h:\Lambda^2(T\Sigma)\to T\Sigma$ is the Hodge star associated to the Lorentzian metric $h$ and the orientation.  This gives a family of (Lorentzian) solutions depending on $3$ functions of $3$ variables locally.

Finally, when $n>2$, there is the natural bi-invariant $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ structure on $M=\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ itself, regarded as a pseudo-Riemannian symmetric space, together its dual symmetric space $M^* = \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})/\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.  By Berger's classification of non-symmetric holonomies (or by simply computing the space of curvatures of this particular $\mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb{R})$-structure and seeing that the only possibility is the locally symmetric one), these are, locally, the only examples when $n>2$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Bryant  I thank  you  very much  for  your answer. I need to spend time to understand the  details. For me, your  answers is usually similar to a paper  so I can not understand it immediately

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  That's fine.  Just ask if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: My appolgy if  my  questions is  elementary: In  your  second  paragraph, what  does it  mean ", there would be an underlying $\nabla$-parallel $\mathrm{PO}(n)$-structure on $M$". and  why is  this  a  consequence  of  compactness of  Holonomy?  My  second  question: In your  answer, are you assuming that the  $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$-structure on $TM$ is  compatible(coincide)   to the differentiation of  some chart  on  $M$? (The  differentiation of  change  of  coordinate)

Comment: .To  be  honest  I  am trying to  understand the details of  your  answer, with the help of wikipedia  and  some  references. What  references  is  more  self contained? Is  5  volumes of  "Spivak" a  good  reference for  some one as me who  do  not have  necessary  background? Can I  find  all  necessary background in this  book?

Comment: Is the  holonomy  of  a  LC connection  necessarily  a  compact maximal  subgroups, as you  pointe  out  to  word  "maximal"?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  As long as the Riemannian manifold is simply connected, the holonomy group is compact (see the holonomy chapter in Besse, "Einstein Manifolds"; I don't have the book with me so I don't have the exact reference) and, hence, must lie in a maximal compact subgroup of the group of automorphisms (in this case, the automorphisms of the algebra structure).

Comment: Dear  Prof.  Bryant,  I  just  received  the  Book  "Einstein  Manifold". Thank  you  very  much  for introducing  me this  very  elegant  book. I  read the  holonomy  chapter  to  understand  your very interesting  answer.

Comment: Dear  Prof.  Bryant. I  am reading  the book of  Besse and  I  have some questions  on various part of the  question. My  questions are  elementary so  I do  not  waste your time  by  my  elementary  questions. I will ask the details  in MSE. Thank  you again for  your  answer.

Answer (score 8):

Every Riemannian metric on the sphere has holonomy $SO(n)$, since the sphere is not a product and not Kaehler unless $n=2$ and has no parallel spinors in any metric. So on the sphere, no Riemannian metric has parallel algebra structure on the tangent bundle.

Comment: The same is true for many compact manifolds, with similar proof.

Comment: Thank  you very  much (and +1) for  your  answer. I try  to  understand its  details.

Comment: thanks again for your answer. Are you referring Berger classification of holonomy group of simply connected manifold. In this case how do we check the local irreducibility?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to restrict your question a bit. When $M$ is $n^2$ dimensional Riemannian flat Euclidean space with Levi-Civita connection, then the parallel transport induced by this is the identity on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. And thus is an algebra isomorphism.

Perhaps you want to look into the notion of Frobenius manifold:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_manifold

There are non-trivial Frobenius manifolds. I think this partially answers maybe what you wanted to ask.